# How do I lowercase/uppercase strings with a shortcut in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I always use shortcut in my terminal such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (cut previous word), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> (cut all in the left) etc.

I'm wondering if I can convert letters to lowercase or uppercase through shortcuts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bash (readline, actually) does have support for this. Check the list of [readline commands for text](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Text.html#Commands-For-Text):

> upcase-word (`M-u`)
>   Uppercase the current (or following) word. With a negative argument,
>   uppercase the previous word, but do not move the cursor.
>
> downcase-word (`M-l`)
>   Lowercase the current (or following) word. With a negative argument,
>   lowercase the previous word, but do not move the cursor.
>
> capitalize-word (`M-c`)
>   Capitalize the current (or following) word. With a negative argument,
>   capitalize the previous word, but do not move the cursor.

`M` here is the Meta key, which is usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the link too. Does the link contain all the possibilities ?

Comment: @smarber yes, the bash documentation section on [bindable readline commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands) (which includes the section I quoted here) does contain all of them. Readline is developed with, and is part of, bash, so bash documentation is authoritative when it comes to readline.

Comment: `ESC` is the meta key. `Alt + U` move point to the end of the word. I'm using zshell.

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to make words uppercase.

Use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> to make words lowercase.

Comment: thanks!! however this converts the word in the right only. Are there other possible shortcuts such as convert to uppercase/lowercase all the line, convert the whole right/left side etc ...

Comment: I'm not aware if such a capability exists :)

Comment: @smarber see the description I quoted - you can covert to the left using negative arguments (Esc, then `-1`, then Alt-U)

Comment: `ESC + u` might work instead of `alt + u`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just came across it when trying to do the same thing.

I did this to capitalize the previous word. (I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this seems to work fine.)

I'm using AutoKey for this. I just created a new script, then added:

```
keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+b")
keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+u")
```

Then bind it with the `Set` button next to `Hotkey`, and it will be active as soon as you save it.

This just jumps to the beginning of the previous word and then uses the already mentioned alt+u shortcut to capitalize it (and, of course, alt+l for lowercase).

I know I'm not going into much detail on this if you haven't used AutoKey, but it's very intuitive, and it should be clear where to put stuff once you open it.

I bound this to `alt+u`, and it works fine. It doesn't execute itself and run an endless loop, because AutoKey only responds to physical keypresses.

You can also use Window Filter (at the bottom of the screen) to restrict this to the terminal so you don't have to deal with it activating in other programs.

Comment: You can tell bash to uppercase the previous word by using [a negative count](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Arguments.html) before `Alt+U`, e.g. `Alt+ - + 1` followed by `Alt+U`